# Kibana visualizations with complex object

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, dataformat

I have documents structured like this on elastic search. I have data tables with columns like

```
driver | vehicle make | vehicle model
```

What I am having trouble is whenever I filter by vehicle make or vehicle model, the whole document is shown. Is there any way to have this kind of filtering by child object working? If I have to have data formatted differently, what would be better format for Kibana and ES?

```
"driver" : {
        "last_name" : "McQueen",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Powell Motors",
                "model" : "Canyonero"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
           }
        ]
    }


"driver" : {
        "last_name" : "Hudson",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Mifune",
                "model" : "Mach Five"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAI understood, you want to select only few fields from document, you can add _source filter while querying like -

"_source": ["driver.last_name","driver.vehicle.make"]

Comment: is that possible during building visualizations in Kibana? I have been looking for some ways to control the query for regular visualizations like bar chart or data table, but haven't found it yet

Comment: thats depends on what kind of visualisation you are creating, for example if you want to show "top_hits" you will have option to select ```vehicle.make``` or ```vehicle.model ``` any of them. Update question or add new question if you have any issue with a specific type of visualisation. 

if this resolves your problem, accept & upwote answer.

Comment: let's say i want to create a pie chart, how do I get the data in that format? `"_source": ["driver.last_name","driver.vehicle.make"]` , I saw that as part of vega, but not sure if vega supports filtering when clicking on a model name

Comment: In Kibana you can choose any of applicable fields of document as per selected aggregation. your question is not clear, be more specific,